# Back-propagation Neural Networks

Tags: neural-network

I have implemented neural networks with back-propagation for learning and it works just fine for XOR but when i tried it for AND and OR it behaves erratic.. during debugging i found out that after certain while in training the output turns 1.0 and is consistent. and when i put the test inputs it returns me 1 only for every case. does this has to do something with bias because i have forced bias to be 1.0 and also do i need to update bias too, though it seems to be a illogical question.. thanks

Comment: What are the specific input vector, activation and error function you are using?

Comment: i am using sigmoid activation function for activation and for error i am just finding difference between the target value and the output i am getting and multiplying it with derivative of the activation function.. i hope this is what you were asking..

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to update bias neuron output value (it is ok to set it to 1), but you do need to update bias weights (weights of connections that come from bias neuron to the layer above).

Comment: i have done that but still somehow its all screwed up.. debugging it for a while now

Comment: You may find [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27646823/4367179) userful as it contains tips about debugging any newly implemented NN. Try following steps outlined there.